# How to retrieve the selected value from dropdown and display it in the same dropdown box

Tags: php, html, select, input, dropdown

I have **three dropdown boxes**. Namely **DS**, **QA**, **Mod**. First step is DS will select a value (YES/NO) & upon submitting, QA will be reviewing the input of DS. I have to get the values of DS Dropdown and display it in the same dropdown box of DS(disabled) when QA is about to check the input.Same goes with Mod.Take note that these dropdown boxes exists in **checklist.php** file.

```html
<table width="100%" border="1">

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="left" rowspan="2"><b>Check Items</b></th>
        <td><b>DS</b></td>
        <td><b>QA</b></td>
        <td><b>Mod?</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" rowspan="2"><select id="valueDS1">
                            <option value="YD1">YES</option>
                            <option value ="NAD1">N/A</option>
                        </select>
      </td>
      <td align="center" rowspan="2"><select id="valueQA1">
                            <option value="YQ2">YES</option>
                            <option value ="NAQ2">N/A</option>
                        </select>
      </td>
      <td align="center" rowspan="2"><select id="valueMod1">
                            <option value="YM1">YES</option>
                            <option value ="NM1">NO</option>
                        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;All extra instructions and corrections applied.</td>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp;If comments exist, ask DE if they need to be deleted or retained (but hidden)</p>
        </td>
        <td align="center"><select id="valueDS2">
                                <option value="Y">YES</option>
                                <option value ="NA">N/A</option>
                            </select>
        </td>
        <td align="center"><select id="valueQA2">
                                <option value="Y">YES</option>
                                <option value ="NA">N/A</option>
                            </select>
        </td>
        <td align="center"><select id="valueMod2">
                                <option value="Y">YES</option>
                                <option value ="NA">NO</option>
                            </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: Can you show the structures of your drop-downs?

Comment: Post the code and show what you have tried to solve the issue

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
in the help documentation. Remember to include Minimal, complete, verifiable examples:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  Then, click `edit` to edit your question so that we may help.

Comment: I added the codes

Answer (score 0):

Inside the PHP code, assign a variable to the dropdown.
`$DS= $_POST['DS']`

Now, in the HTML of the dropdown do something like following

```
<select>
    <option <?php if(isset($DS) && $DS=="yes" ){ echo "selected"; } ?> value="yes" disabled>Yes</option>
</select>
```

Comment: We really need to stop blind firing let him show what he has done so we can give a better answer.